# Easy way to trigger a switch via USB?

Tags: usb

I'm not really into electronics but for some projects I would like to be able to control some real hardware with a computer. So I'm looking for a solution that I can simply plug into my USB port and that (ideally without any additional drivers) will let me trigger a switch (to turn a LED on and off for an example) using say python code. Is there such solution/board/interface out there?

(I don't want to use an Arduino or similar, just looking for an interface)

Comment: What reason have you for not wanting to use Ardiono or similar?

Comment: Well, from what i understand, the idea of things like the Arduino is that they can run by themself, without a computer. This of course brings limitations like limited processing power, limited (or more complex) connectivity etc. Since i don't need a device that runs without a computer this would simply be overhead for me..

Comment: If you attach hardware to the PC, then a (device) driver is involved; otherwise the PC would not know how to interface with the device.

Comment: I was hoping for something that doesn't need an *additional* driver so maybe something that registers as a joystick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a google search for "usb relay switch". A relay is an electromechanical switch that can be (remotely) toggled electrically.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be pretty much what i was looking for!